# How to manipulate pixels of rendered screen or Display Object in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, pixel-bender

My game engine doesn't render into a BitmapData like Flixel/Flashpunk does.
Instead it uses the Display list of Flash player internally.

I need to do some post processing, like scan lines, and wobble, glitch etc on the final rendered screen (e.g- http://goo.gl/Enwae). I have done render-to-texture in OpenGL and used a pixel shader used to manipulate the final rendered scene.

How do I implement the equivalent of same in Actionscript 3? I saw the reference for Pixel Bender and Shader Filter classes. Can someone give a simple example or point me to relevant information to the context specified here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you'll need to render the screen to BitmapData at some point if you want to manipulate the pixels in that way.

You could try using [BitmapData.draw()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29) to render the entire stage to BitmapData, but performance will most likely be miserable unless you're just using it on a fairly static screen (like a menu).

Otherwise you're probably better off with a game engine that blits to a bitmap canvas instead of using the display list.